# ASP/C# dropdown caues an error when current value is not part of the dropdown items

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

First C#/ASP project!  I am using Visual Studio, with `gridviews` that have an "Update" button.  When in "update" mode, `dropdowns` are populated from a database to limit choices.  The tables that populate the `dropdowns` have an "active" column, which determines if that row will be displayed in the `dropdown` or not.

The issue is, when an row in the `gridview` contains data that has been marked as inactive, it displays fine.  Then, if the "update" button is pushed, the `dropdown` gets populated, and cant display data that is not part of its active dataset.

Example:

If a department was historically called Math/Science(CS), but its name was changed to Computer Science.  Therefore Math/Science(CS) would be marked as "inactive" so it couldn't be selected anymore.  A Professor who worked in the 80's would have belonged to the old department.  If we needed to edit that row - as soon as the `dropdown` was populated, the application will crash because Math/Science(CS) is not part of the data set for the `dropdown`.

So, is there anyway around this type of issue?

Comment: Sounds like a perfectly ordinary software problem.  If the item should be in the model then keep it in there.

Comment: I agree with LordWilmore, this is a big problem if you've changed the data (dept name) but still have the department name in other tables.  This means you've left yourself with "bad data".  A better way to set up your data would be a Department table with a key relationship to the personnel table.  Then you could change the name of the department since it is just for display and you are actually saving the key to the lookup table.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys/gals  What I did was write a new SQL statement to grab all the "accepted" data, and also include the "current" data.  Having the current data included in the dropdown avoids errors, and also helps us keep track of historical data.